# How to specify HGT file name in gdal_translate command?

Tags: gdal-translate, srtm, hgt

**gdal_translate** command is generating a HGT file with user defined name but its giving an error as ***`N5464347W74.hgt' not recognized as a supported file format.*** Below is the command and the entire output.

```
**gdal_translate -of SRTMHGT 1e9815c1-b74e-4a75-8a98-844d730707e7.tif user_def.hgt**

Input file size is 1201, 1201
Warning 1: The corner coordinates of the source are not properly aligned on plain latitude/longitude boundaries.
Warning 1: Expected output filename is N48W002.HGT.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
ERROR 4: `N5464347W74.hgt' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

But if we provide the file name suggested by the command then it runs error free. Not sure how can we extract the file name. following is the ***gdalinfo*** for the tif file.

```
**gdalinfo 1e9815c1-b74e-4a75-8a98-844d730707e7.tif**

Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 1e9815c1-b74e-4a75-8a98-844d730707e7.tif
Size is 1201, 1201
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-1.686258165938839,48.111195526365400)
Pixel Size = (0.000002416422364,-0.000001681829966)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -1.6862582,  48.1111955) (  1d41'10.53"W, 48d 6'40.30"N)
Lower Left  (  -1.6862582,  48.1091756) (  1d41'10.53"W, 48d 6'33.03"N)
Upper Right (  -1.6833560,  48.1111955) (  1d41' 0.08"W, 48d 6'40.30"N)
Lower Right (  -1.6833560,  48.1091756) (  1d41' 0.08"W, 48d 6'33.03"N)
Center      (  -1.6848071,  48.1101856) (  1d41' 5.31"W, 48d 6'36.67"N)
Band 1 Block=1201x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=0
  Unit Type: metre
```

Any suggestions???

Comment: If gdalinfo does not report the filename you can perhaps take the lower left coordinates and generate the filename from those https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/Documentation/Quickstart.pdf.

Comment: Thanks @user30184. I'm using gdalinfo to get that value and will format my file name.